# Create all combinations from regex

Tags: python, regex

I have sentences that define a template for random combinations:

```
I like dogs/cats    
I want to eat today/(the next day)
```

I tried using a regex:

```
m = re.search(r'(?P<list>[A-Za-z]+/([A-Za-z]+)+)', sentence)
words = m.group('list').split('/')
combs = [comb for comb in [sentence.replace(m.group('list'), w) for w in words]]
```

For the first sentence I get `['i like dogs', 'i like cats']` which is what I want. For the second sentence, `re.search` returns `None`. What I would like to get is `['I want to eat today', 'I want to eat the next day']`.

How do I need to change the regex?

Answer (score 0):

(I want to eat today)*|(the next day)

Is the regex that will select the text you want...

Comment: Use this tool https://regex101.com/ Wish I had it when I started. The best way that I've found to write perfect regex is by using this tool... you'll pick up regex really fast. Paste your "text in which you will search through in the largest box" and write "your regex" in the small box above. Automatically text will be highlighted based on your regex. To the bottom right you can read the definitions and top right tells you why things were selected.

Comment: No. From the given template `I want to eat today/(the next day)` I want to create two sentences: `['I want to eat today', 'I want to eat the next day']`. Thus, I need to find `today` and `the next day`.

Answer (score 0):

`r'(?P<list>[A-Za-z]+/([a-zA-Z]+|\(.+?\)))''`

`([a-zA-Z]+|\(.+?\))` matches strings like "word" or "(some word)". And it also matches "()", we need to remove heading "(" and trailing ")" using `strip`.

```
m = re.search(r'(?P<list>[A-Za-z]+/([a-zA-Z]+|\(.+?\)))', sentence)
words = m.group('list').split('/')
combs = [comb for comb in [sentence.replace(m.group('list'), w.strip('()')) for w in words]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With below code you will get something like

```
> sentence = 'I want to eat today/(the next day)' m =
> re.search(r'(?P<list>[A-Za-z]+/([A-Za-z]+|(\(.*?\))))', sentence)
> print m.group('list') words = m.group('list').split('/') combs = [comb
> for comb in [sentence.replace(m.group('list'), w) for w in words]]
> print combs

['I want to eat today', 'I want to eat (the next day)'
```

you could dome extra processing to get rid of the extra parenthesis which should be easy